# cannot load shared library that exists in /usr/local/lib (Fedora x64)

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, 64-bit, fedora

When attempting to run a program I just compiled successfully, I get the following error:

> ./src/sensors/laser_scan_producer: error while loading shared libraries: ***liblcm.so.1***: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

`ls /usr/local/lib/liblcm*` yields

```
/usr/local/lib/liblcm.la  
/usr/local/lib/liblcm.so  
/usr/local/lib/liblcm.so.1  
/usr/local/lib/liblcm.so.1.2.0
```

I have executed `sudo ldconfig` several times and added /usr/local/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the sake of redundancy.

This exhausts the list of answers I've seen whilst grepping around stackOverflow.

Anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Is it possible the linker is looking in /usr/local/lib64/?

Comment: `ldconfig` uses the file `/etc/ld.so.conf`. You can add `/usr/local/lib` to that file, re-run `ldconfig` and try again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thank you to @Joachim_Pileborg:

> ldconfig uses the file /etc/ld.so.conf. You can add /usr/local/lib to
>   that file, re-run ldconfig and try again

Doing so fixed the problem, although I find it odd that /usr/local/lib wouldn't have been checked in the natural course of things.

Comment: `ldconfig` uses a cache of the files in the directory, so simply adding the file to the directory isn't sufficient.  You must run `sudo ldconfig` in order to update the cache

Comment: Simply running `sudo ldconfig` was enough. For whatever reason, be it this particular package or aptitude itself, `apt install` didn't seem to correctly install the package so even though I could link against it I couldn't run my program. After running `ldconfig`, it just automagically started running correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I found a working solution for both /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/lib64 directories [in this commit](https://github.com/Nuand/bladeRF/commit/63c5be310564074a1f161e8f6fcf39a421eeaeda).

First run this command as root to add those directories.

```
tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf <<EOF
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib64
EOF
```

Next run as root:

```
ldconfig
```