# Ubuntu 13.04 | Getting SFML-2.0 to compile

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, sfml

I am trying to get SFML-2.0 to work with Ubuntu 13.04

I am following [this](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-linux.php) guide, but I seem to be having trouble finding all the components of the SFML library.  I downloaded SFML from the download page and put it in usr/local.

If anyone has gotten SFML to work with a different IDE or method, I would definitely be willing to try that as well.

[image: These are the commands I used, the code, and files.]

Comment: Possibly the same issue than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045563/cannot-load-shared-library-that-exists-in-usr-local-lib-fedora-x64

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this tutorial it should work:

http://sfmlcoder.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/building-sfml-2-0-with-make-for-gcc/

then put the sfml 2 folder with all the dependencies inside of your /usr/include/ folder and compile with `g++ main.o -o main -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system` and run with with `./main` it should work perfectly. I actually setup a key mapping in vim that compiles using that command and then runs it and its works flawlessly for me.