# GDAL error on CentOS 7

Tags: java, centos, gis, gdal, geokettle

I’m no IT guy so it’s possible that I making something very wrong. But I’m struggling for days with this issue…

Working in a VM with CentOS 7.
When running something in GeoKettle I have this error that points to GDAL.

```
Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/geoairc/QGIS_Install/geokettle/libswt/linux/x86_64/libogrjni.so: liblcms.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
INFO  29-05 10:10:37,639 - OGR Input - wfs xml geodomus.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=0)
Exception in thread "OGR Input - wfs xml geodomus.0 (Thread-10)" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.ogr.ogrJNI.RegisterAll()V
    at org.gdal.ogr.ogrJNI.RegisterAll(Native Method)
    at org.gdal.ogr.ogr.RegisterAll(ogr.java:110)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.geospatial.OGRReader.open(OGRReader.java:75)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.ogrfileinput.OGRFileInputMeta.getOutputFields(OGRFileInputMeta.java:277)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.ogrfileinput.OGRFileInput.processRow(OGRFileInput.java:172)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.ogrfileinput.OGRFileInput.run(OGRFileInput.java:342)
```

Someone pointed me that the error was caused by the lack of GDAL bindings to Java.
So I installed gdal-java RPM

https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/7/x86_64/g/gdal-java-1.11.4-1.el7.x86_64.html

I installed but get successive dependency errors that can not get past (this is the first but when I try to install one of this got another set of dependencies errors):

```
[root@srvlgis01 tmp]# rpm -Uvh gdal-java-1.11.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        gdal-libs(x86-64) = 1.11.4-1.el7 is needed by gdal-java-1.11.4-1.el7.x86_64
        libgeotiff.so.1.2()(64bit) is needed by gdal-java-1.11.4-1.el7.x86_64
```

My GDAL version: `gdal.x86_64 0:1.11.4-10.rhel7`

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045563/cannot-load-shared-library-that-exists-in-usr-local-lib-fedora-x64

Comment: You should have installed `gdal-java` using `yum` by adding EPEL repositories to your system so that `yum` could take care of dependencies.